# Register a new user using the coinbase API?

Tags: coinbase-api

We are creating a DiFi app and I'd like our customers to be able to sign up to coinbase and go through KYC/AML so they have an account in their name, but without them having to leave our site. The reason we want them to have their own account is that we are not regulated to handle customer's fiat funds - though we are able to manipulate funds in a customer's account if they give us permission,

Is it possible to register new users onto coinbase through the coinbase APIs or do users need to go to the coinbase website to sign up?

Answer (score -1):

Being able to register for another service through your service can open an array of security vulnerabilities. You could do it by reverse-engineering their API, but it would certainly be questionable.

Instead, the Coinbase API does have [OAuth2](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/coinbase-connect). This would allow your users to connect their accounts in a secure manner.

You can find the integration instructions [here](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/coinbase-connect/integrating).

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, I can see it would not be an easy thing to provide securely. 

The reason I thought is might be possible is that I have been looking at companies like Modulr, Contis and CurrencyCloud and they all allow you to create (fiat) accounts in the name of your customers in the way I described. But most Crypto ramp services to not allow this (BitStamp, Kraken etc.)